# twitter analytics export using java

Tags: java, twitter

Hai i am new to twitter integration can any one know how to export twitter analytics data using java

Answer (score 0):

You can use twitter4j api for this, of course it is not an official twitter api, but it is good one to use, you can find some examples in their download also.
http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html

Comment: In twitter4j they are not providing twitter analytics data

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a python package that does just that. It's a bit hackish but works.

$ pip install twitter-analytics

More here: https://github.com/philippe2803/twitter-analytics-wrapper